# Doing nodemon -r dotenv/config index.js

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, nodemon, dotenv

For maximum portability I'm not doing `import 'dotenv/config'` within my code, but I'm doing

`node -r dotenv/config index.js`

Now, I'm starting to use `nodemon`, which says in README,

> To use `nodemon`, replace the word `node` on the command line when executing your script.

However, when I'm doing `nodemon -r dotenv/config index.js`, I only get an usage prompt:

```
  Usage: nodemon [nodemon options] [script.js] [args]

  See "nodemon --help" for more.
```

Is hard-coding `import 'dotenv/config'` within my code the only option that I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`--exec`](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/07159c573d9076cff869c936cc5fbc0d00f88160/doc/cli/options.txt#L18) you can specify the exact command you want nodemon to run your script against, which lets you specify `-r`.

So in your case it would be:

```
nodemon --exec "node -r dotenv/config" index.js
```

Comment: Bravo!!! I thought there should be some ways. Thanks! You're so fast and I'll have to wait for 5+ minutes to accept your answer, :)

Comment: Hmm.. slifty, seems there is no different between calling `nodemon --exec node -r dotenv/config index.js` and `nodemon --exec "node -r dotenv/config" index.js`. Any specific reasons you add the quotations afterwards?

Comment: Answering my question myself. Yes, when put in `CMD` within Dockerfile, only the quoted format works.

Comment: I actually *didn't* use quotes in my project, but added them to my answer after I saw the documented example included quotes.  I think in your case it might not matter but in the general case using quotes could be important (e.g. if someone finds this answer and their command included a flag that nodemon could misinterpret as a nodemon flag)

Comment: Oh good to know -- that too then! ;)